# Disable Sidebar in the Product Page in Storefront Theme

Tags: themes, woocommerce-offtopic, sidebar

I am using storefront theme, where there is options for the Full Width in the pages but not in the Product Page and Product Category Page in the Store Front Theme

As i played with css and i go this line in the template

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
```

As i removed the content-area class i can able to remove the space of the sidebar, but that is not what i was expected, because it is removing sidebar in whole website

I need to remove it only in product page but not in product-category page, how this can be achieved in the storefront theme

Comment: Can you post a link of your website ?

Answer (score 2):

for product page, you can put in functions.php

```
function remove_storefront_sidebar() {
    if ( is_product() ) {
    remove_action( 'storefront_sidebar', 'storefront_get_sidebar', 10 );
    }
}
add_action( 'get_header', 'remove_storefront_sidebar' );
```

It works with latest woocommerce 2.5.2
Also CSS is needed:

```
.single-product.right-sidebar .content-area {
  float: none;
  margin-right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You need to define `.single-product.left-sidebar .content-area` in the case of the left sidebar. So, I guess that `.single product .content-area` is a universal solution, isn't it?

Answer (score -1):

just go to theme options, select woocommerce, and change the product, shop, and categories layout to 1 column (instead of 2 column with sidebar)